# need help to remove slice out functionality from apex:chart

Tags: apex, visualforce

sfdc folks ...i need to remove  slice out functionality from apex:chart from my vf page...

here is vf page ::

```
>     <apex:chart height="130" width="230" data="{!PieData}" animate="false" >
>         <apex:pieSeries dataField="data" labelField="name" >
>             <apex:chartLabel display="none" />
>             <apex:chartTips height="20" width="120"/> 
>         </apex:pieSeries>
>         <apex:legend position="right" />
>     </apex:chart> </apex:page>
```

and here is controller ::

```
//for pie chart 
   public List<PieWedgeData> getPieData() {
    system.debug('<<<<in pie method');
        List<PieWedgeData> data = new List<PieWedgeData>();
        data.add(new PieWedgeData('Test1', 200));
        data.add(new PieWedgeData('Test2', 300));
        //data.add(new PieWedgeData('Test3', 200));
        system.debug('<<<<in pie method list '+data);
        return data;
    }
    // Wrapper class for pie chart
    public class PieWedgeData {

        public String name { get; set; }
        public Decimal data { get; set; }

        public PieWedgeData(String name, Decimal data) {
            this.name = name;
            this.data = data;
        }
    }
```

[image]

Appreciate the help.

Comment: What have you already tried to remove it? What exactly do you mean by "slice out functionality?"

Comment: Thanx for reply..i tried every option sir...and by "slice out functionality" means when we take our mouse curser on chart ...at that time chart get slice little out ..so that slicing i want to stop..
will attach image to clarify..